# Copy Substring of Column into Another Column

Tags: mysql

My client had input both the city and state (ex: Atlanta, GA) in the city field. The city field is in the `rmn_wpjb_job` table in a column named `job_city`.
I want to be able to put the state portion of what the client had entered in the `job_state` column which has all empty rows right now. The end result would have just the city in the `job_city` column and the state in the `job_state` column. I would need to remove the comma in the `job_city` column.

My web hosting support gave me this query to start:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(job_city, ',', -1) 
FROM `rmn_wpjb_job`
```

This works fine, but I want to take the results of this query and put it into the job_state column.

There are 500 rows that I need to do this for. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If you know how to get the substring, and you know how to do an `UPDATE` query, why don't you know how to put the two together?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an `UPDATE` operation

```
update rmn_wpjb_job 
set job_state = SUBSTRING_INDEX(job_city, ',', -1)
where <some_condtion_if_needed>;
```